# Use function in HTML form to specifc camps

Tags: javascript, html

I want to when I click the button it will add what I wrote in the field with the prefix say and send it through POST, the POST is working fine because if I don't use the script it will send it but without the "prefix"

```
    <script>
        function say() {
          document.actionsv.command.value = ("say " + "\"" + document.COMMOM.SAY.value + "\"");
          document.actionsv.submit();
        }
    </script>

    <form action='' method='post' name="actionsv">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-8">
             <div class="card">
                <div class="card-content">
                   <div class="">
                    <form name='COMMOM'>
                      <table class="table table-hover-animation mb-0 table-striped">
                         <thead>
                            <tr>
                               <th></th>
                               <th class="o"></th>
                            </tr>
                         </thead>
                         <tbody>
                            <tr>
                               <td>   
                                  <input type="text" name="SAY" autocomplete="off" value="" class="form-control">
                               </td>
                               <td align="center"><button type="submit" value="Say" onclick="say()" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">MSAY</button></td>
                            </tr>
                         </tbody>
                      </table>
                    </form>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div> 
    </form>
```

I've tried everything but can't get it to work.. 
This is the error in console: http://prntscr.com/oq4084

Comment: Make a fiddle so we can help you out!

Comment: You have a form inside other form, that is why it's returning undefined.

Comment: @Marco hmmm what would be the best to do it then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There more than one error with your code. I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8ujnz6gt/) for you.

```
  <script>
    function say()
    {
    console.log("say " + "\"" + document.actionsv.elements['SAY'].value + "\"");
    document.actionsv.submit();
    }
</script>

<form action='' method='post' name="actionsv">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-8">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content">
               <div class="">
                <form name='COMMOM'>
                  <table class="table table-hover-animation mb-0 table-striped">
                     <thead>
                        <tr>
                           <th></th>
                           <th class="o"></th>
                        </tr>
                     </thead>
                     <tbody>
                        <tr>
                           <td>   
                              <input type="text" name="SAY" autocomplete="off" value="" class="form-control">
                           </td>
                           <td align="center"><button type="submit" value="Say" onclick="say()" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light">MSAY</button></td>
                        </tr>
                     </tbody>
                  </table>
                </form>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

You are poiting the result ta element that doesn't exist (document.actionsv.command) and you were using the forms array wrong. I don't know what you were trying to do with document.actionsv.command so i made e console.log with the result.